# How to make reporting server to save a generated report in a share path automatically?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I've an existing report which is generated when user passes parameters from the UI. Now, I want the reporting server to save the generated report into the share folder automatically rather than making user to store it.
So, whenever user generates a report the reporting server should automatically store the report into a share path.
I know we can have SSRS subscription which can schedule reports and save it in a share path, but is it possible to generate a report dynamically(when user wants to)?

I searched over internet and read few articles but they aren't helping.
Any idea/solution will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean create from scratch? Your question isn't too clear on `generate a report dynamically(when a user wants to)?`

Comment: Apologies for that. I've an existing report and able to generate it. Now, I want to save this report automatically in a share path (the way it is done by SSRS subscription) that means each and every time when a user generates a report, the report should be saved in a share path automatically.

Comment: I also am not clear on your question.  Are you aware that an SSRS instance makes available a website endpoint which provides interactive access to collections of reports that can be run when a user wants to, dynamically?  This includes the capabilities which allow the user to choose parameters for the dynamic invocation of the report, as well as save the output to a share.

Comment: Agree with @DavidTansey. The SSRS Portal should have all of your reports visible to the end users for on-demand use.

Comment: David, I'm aware of that and the present report works in the same manner as you described, but rather than user saving it into a share path I want the report to be saved into a shared place by the reporting server automatically.

Comment: So, when the user runs the report. You want it saved into a shared folder without the user downloading it?

Comment: @WEI_DBA, Exactly :)

Comment: What format are you downloading to?

Comment: @WEI_DBA, The report will be downloaded in PDF format.

Comment: If you have a stored procedure running this report, you could also run the subscription for this report from the stored proc. But I'm still trying to figure out how to dynamically fill the parameters in the subscription from t-sql.

Comment: Potential solution. http://geekswithblogs.net/LifeLongTechie/archive/2009/11/24/calling-ssrs-report-using-either-t-sql-or-ssis.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information. Think if we can use the data driven subscription in this case. The values entered by user can be stored into a table and then the subscription can be triggered from the SP.